# How to find total number of records/rows in gridview?

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview, gridviewrow

I want to find total number of rows in the gridview. here is my code, page size= 10

```
   Private Sub GridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles CustomGridView1.RowDataBound
    Dim Count As Integer = CustomGridView1.Rows.Count()
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        e.Row.Cells(5).Text = Count & " of " & getstudents.Count()
    End If
End Sub
```

Footer shows as, 10 0f 50 in the first page but I want to show as 1-10 of 50 . In the second page it shows the same but I want to show as 11-20 of 50. Can anyone tell me how to show footer text like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah you have to declare a variable to assign the value of that function to.

```
Dim int as integer

int = CustomGridView1.Rows.Count()
```

The .Count() function returns an integer value. You must store that integer value somewhere, otherwise there is no point in calling the function.

Edit-----

Maybe something like this

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
            e.Row.Cells(2).Text = (variable you defined above)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Just my best guess on this one. I don't usually use the footers.

Comment: I want to store the int value and display it in my gridview footer. any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4804992/1157215 This guy seems to be doing kind of the same thing you are.